# Rails 3 Devise Warden Login security hole that needs to be plugged, pulling my hair out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, devise, warden

I have an issue with my login functionality.

1. When user clicks the logout link eveything works normally, session is destroyed and user can log in as a different user.
2. If a currently signed in user closes the browser and comes back to the login page, or if the user simply presses the back button to the login page
   and attempts to sign in as a different user, the user is directed to the user previously logged in to the application on that particular browser.
   This is not wanted functionality.  I would like to give the user the ability to sign into whatever account they want to regardless of 
   whether or not the user backs into the login page, or closes the window and comes back to the login page.

   I have tried 6 different solutions and none of them have worked.  It seems that no matter the change I make to the code the login functionality always pulls
   the user id from a session[:warden.user.person.key] hash and uses it to login no matter what is put into the login text field.  I have tried to gain control of this process
   but have failed at every attempt.

   I have run out of ideas and need some help for this has been deemed a security hole in our system.
   Please let me kow what else you would like to see for code.  I'm giving you the session controller code and my routes.

```
 
class SessionsController  Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    session["devise.omniauth_data"]=nil
    session[:last_registration_role]=nil
    super
  end
  def create
    if params['person']['remember_me'] == '1'
      cookies.signed['rem'] = {
        :value => params['person']['email'],
        :expires => 1.year.from_now,
        :httponly => true
      }
    end
    super
  end
  def destroy

    session["devise.omniauth_data"]=nil
    session[:last_registration_role]=nil
    super
    reset_session
  end    
end
```

Routes

```
                     new_person_session GET      /people/sign_in(.:format)                                                                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
                                    person_session POST     /people/sign_in(.:format)                                                                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
                            destroy_person_session GET      /people/sign_out(.:format)                                                                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                                   person_password POST     /people/password(.:format)                                                                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                               new_person_password GET      /people/password/new(.:format)                                                                      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                              edit_person_password GET      /people/password/edit(.:format)                                                                     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                                                   PUT      /people/password(.:format)                                                                          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
```

Comment: Is the app intended to run in on public (multi-user) machines? Or is this something you're encountering in user acceptance testing?

Comment: Yes it will be running on multi user machines, also there is a case where a user could have two different account types with different login credentials. i.e. A merchant account and a consumer account, merchant account with joesmith@businessname.com and consumer account with joesmith@gmail.com
Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: When you hit the back button, does the previous user log back in? Or does it simply show the page with the previous user logged in and then when you refresh the page it just shows the page with nobody logged in? I have a site with devise and that's what happens to me. Which, now that I've noticed, is unintended.

Comment: When pressing the back button to the login page it gives me the login screen with the username/email prepopulated with the currently logged in user and a blank password field.  If I ctrl+f5 it refreshes to a fresh login with blank username and password fields.  I then try to login as a different user but it still logs in as the previous user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application_controller, try setting the exact location you want people to be sent after signing in:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```

Comment: Jesse your solution worked great: here it is taylored to what I needed.  @Ashitaka thismay help you to.
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_out  #force sign out of currently signed in user
    return current_person #redirect accordingly
    end

Comment: You can't format comments :P All you can do is wrap `some code in a single line`. But I get it anyway, I'm going to try it now. Thanks!